# Find $a\in (0,\infty)$ such that $a^x-x^a\geq0 \forall x>0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

> Find $a\in (0,\infty)$ such that $a^x-x^a\geq0 \forall x >0$

My attempt:

Let $f(x)=a^x-x^a$  then $f'(x)=a^x\ln a -ax^{a-1}$. $f'(x)=0\implies a^{x-1}\ln a=x^{a-1}$... and I can't really solve this equation. How should I approach this question differently?

Comment: Hint: $a^x\geq{}x^a \iff xlna\geq{}alnx$ so you need to study the function $f(x)=ln(x)/x$

Comment: What value of $x$ has f(x) =0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* Consider $g(x)=x^{1/x}$. Find its maximum.

Comment: Thank you, found out that $g(x)$ has it's maximum at $x = e$ and therefore $a = e^{\frac {1}e}$.

Comment: @C.Cristi, you mean, $a=e$.

Comment: yeah, right.....

Answer (score 1):

Making $a = e$ we have

$$
e^{\frac{1}{e}} \ge x^{1/x}
$$

Comment: While true, you've not made clear how this is connected to the OP. I'd either do that, or make clear that this is a hint.

Comment: It is obvious because $a^x  \ge x^a $ is equivalent to $a^{\frac{1}{a}} \ge x^{\frac{1}{x}}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Consider the function $h(x)=\frac{\ln(x)}{x}$ and note that for $x>0$,
$$a^x\geq x^a\Leftrightarrow x\ln(a)\geq a\ln(x)\Leftrightarrow  h(a)\geq h(x).$$
By evaluating the derivative of $h$, you should be able to find the point of global maximum $a$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=x\ln (a)-a \ln (x)$. If $a \geq 1$ then $f'(x)=\ln (a)-\frac a x$ which is 0 when $x=\frac a {\ln (a)}$. $f$ has minimum at this point so we need $a-a\ln {\frac a {\ln (a)}} \geq 0$. If $a<1$ then $f$ is decreasing tends to $-\infty$ so there is no $a$ for which $f$ is non-negative for all $x$. So the condition on $a$ is $a \geq 1$ and $\frac a {\ln (a)} \leq e$ or